# Image data is corrupted while encoding-decoding using RSA algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, encryption

My task is to implement RSA algorithm image encryption. I am generating RSA parameters, then loading image from file, encrypting , decrypting and then saving new image to file. The problem is when the image is displayed it seems like the bottom part of image is corrupted and not decrypted well. Do you have any ideas what is wrong in my code?

```
from PIL import Image
import io
from Crypto.Util.number import long_to_bytes
from Crypto.Util.number import inverse
from Crypto.Util.number import getPrime
from Crypto.Util.number import GCD
from Crypto.Util.number import bytes_to_long
from Crypto.Util.number import getRandomRange


blockSize = 255

def loadImage():
    with io.BytesIO() as recivedPicture:
        with Image.open("IMG2.jpg") as picture:
            picture.save(recivedPicture, 'JPEG')
        returnVal = recivedPicture.getvalue()
    return returnVal


def saveImage(decryptedImg):
    picture = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decryptedImg))
    picture.save("rsa_photo_copy.jpg", picture.format)
    print("Hacking procedure finished success!\n")


def proceedRSA(n, e, d):
    eByteArray = bytearray()
    dByteArray = bytearray()
    print("Hacking procedure begin\n")
    for i in range(0, len(loadImage()), blockSize):
        blockData = loadImage()[i:i + blockSize]
        eByteArray.extend(encryptFunction(blockData, e, n))
        dByteArray.extend(decryptFunction(encryptFunction(blockData, e, n), d, n))
    saveImage(dByteArray)

def encryptFunction(data, e, n):
    m = bytes_to_long(data)
    c = pow(m, e, n)
    value = long_to_bytes(c)
    return value


def decryptFunction(data, d, n):
    c = bytes_to_long(data)
    m = pow(c, d, n)
    value = long_to_bytes(m)
    return value


def main():
    # odnalezienie 1024 bitowej liczby pierwszej q
    q = getPrime(1024)
    # odnalezienie 1024 bitowej liczby pierwszej p
    p = getPrime(1024)
    # powtórzenie losowania p tak długo jak p jest różne od q
    while q==p:
        p = getPrime(1024)
        pass
    # znalezienie n = p*q
    n = p * q
    # znalezienie f = (p-1) * (q-1)
    f = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    # znalezienie e
    e = getRandomRange(1, f - 1)
    while GCD(e, f) != 1:
        e = getRandomRange(1, f - 1)
    # znalezienie d
    d = inverse(e, f)
    # wywołanie algorytmu
    proceedRSA(n, e, d)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: When you run this on a plain text file instead of an image, what happens? The nature of the corruption in that case should be more apparent, and should make it more obvious what the problem is.

Comment: In my opinion it's asking too much to read up on obscure methods in an abandoned crypto library. One red flag is the method `long_to_bytes()`. This method may return fewer than 256 bytes in some fraction of cases. If this happens to just one block then that block and all subsequent ones are messed up. You really should be using hybrid encryption and a real crypto library.

Answer (score 0):

Plain / textbook RSA is utterly insecure.

However, as a practice, you should know that you can indeed not encrypt 256 bytes of random data for a 2048 bit key, as the value as unsigned big integer may be larger than the modulus. However, the result will often require 256 bytes. So the block size of the plaintext must be smaller than that of the ciphertext.

This would be avoided if you could split single bits, as only the highest bit must be 0 more often than 1. But yeah, no such luck, bits are more atomic than atoms.

You can find this out by debugging your code.